# How to derive the variance of the forward step of Variational Diffusion Models in terms of the log signal-to-noise ratio $\lambda_t$?

Tags: diffusion-models

Regarding Eq. (1) in [Progressive Distillation for Fast Sampling of Diffusion Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.00512),
$$
q(\mathbf{z}_t|\mathbf{z}_s) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{z}_t; (\alpha_t/\alpha_s)\mathbf{z}_s, \sigma _{t|s}^2 \mathbf{I})
\tag{1}
$$
, it says $\sigma_{t|s}^2 = (1 - e^{\lambda_t - \lambda_s})\sigma_t^2$.

I believe $\sigma_{t|s}$ is from DDPM's $\beta$, then it's equivalent to $1 - \alpha_t^2 / \alpha_s^2$ here. Note that $\lambda_t = \log (\alpha_t^2 / \sigma_t^2)$. As far as I understand, $\sigma_t^2 + \alpha_t^2 = 1$. Maybe I'm taking something wrong.

Anyway, how could $\sigma_{t|s}^2 = (1 - e^{\lambda_t - \lambda_s})\sigma_t^2$ be derived from $1 - \alpha_t^2 / \alpha_s^2$?

Some more notes.

- More papers are using the same expression.

  - [Classifier-Free Diffusion Guidance](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.12598)
  - [Video Diffusion Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.03458)
  - [Imagen Video: High Definition Video Generation with Diffusion Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.02303)
- I think the definition of $\sigma_{t|s}$ Eq. (22) in [the original VDM paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.00630) is straightforward with respect to DDPM's definitions.
- The expression seems to be quite similar to Eq.(32) of VDM.

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleagues gave me a solution. (Thanks Ken!)

$$
{\begin{aligned}
\sigma_{t|s}^2 &= 1 - \alpha_{t|s}^2 \\
&= 1 - {\alpha_t^2 \over \alpha_s^2} \\
&= {\alpha_s^2 - \alpha_t^2 \over \alpha_s^2} \\
&= {(1 - \sigma_s^2)-(1-\sigma_t^2) \over \alpha_s^2} \\
&= {\sigma_t^2 - \sigma_s^2 \over \alpha_s^2} \\
&= {\sigma_t^2 (\alpha_s^2 + \sigma_s^2) - \sigma_s^2 (\alpha_t^2 + \sigma_t^2) \over \alpha_s^2} \\
&= {\sigma_t^2 \alpha_s^2 - \sigma_s^2 \alpha_t^2 \over \alpha_s^2} \\
&= \left(1 -{\sigma_s^2 \alpha_t^2 \over \alpha_s^2 \sigma_t^2}\right) \sigma_t^2 \\
&= \left(1 -{1 \over e^{\lambda_s}}\cdot e^{\lambda_t}\right) \sigma_t^2 \\
&= \left(1 - e^{\lambda_t - \lambda_s}\right) \sigma_t^2 \\
\end{aligned}}
$$
given
$$
\alpha_t^2 + \sigma_t^2 = 1 \\
\alpha_{t|s}^2 + \sigma_{t|s}^2 = 1 \\
e^{\lambda_t} = {\alpha_t^2 \over \sigma_t^2}
$$
.

Answer (score 1):

There is another derivation:
$$
{\begin{aligned}
\sigma_{t|s}^2 &:= \sigma_t^2 - {\alpha_{t}^2 \over \alpha_s^2} \sigma_s^2 \\
&= \left( 1 - {\alpha_t^2 \sigma_s^2\over \sigma_t^2\alpha_s^2} \right) \sigma_t^2\\
&= \left(1 -e^{\lambda_t}\cdot {1 \over e^{\lambda_s}}\right) \sigma_t^2 \\
&= \left(1 - e^{\lambda_t - \lambda_s}\right) \sigma_t^2 \\
\end{aligned}}
$$

given
$$
e^{\lambda_t} = {\alpha_t^2 \over \sigma_t^2}
$$
.